# Activation hook not creating table

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql, wpdb

For some reason my activation hook is not creating new database table.

Code:

```
function mm_booking_activate() {
    global $wpdb;
    $mm_booking_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mm_booking";
    $mm_booking_db_version = '1.0';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE ' . $mm_booking_table_name ) != $mm_booking_table_name ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $mm_booking_table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            first_name varchar(255),
            last_name varchar(255),
            address varchar(255),
            lat decimal(10, 8) NOT NULL,
            lng decimal(11, 8) NOT NULL,
            field enum('option1', 'option2', 'option3'),
            phone_number varchar(255),
            email varchar(255),
            date_time_from datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            date_time_to datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      status enum('pending', 'approved', 'rejected') DEFAULT 'pending',
      modification_time datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      creation_time datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( 'mm_booking_db_version', $mm_booking_db_version );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mm_booking_activate' );
```

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? Any error messages? Have you verified that your function fires on activation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name needs to be in quotes on the line where you're checking if it exists. I tested it, and after that was fixed, the table was successfully created. Here is the full code:

```
function mm_booking_activate() {
    global $wpdb;
    $mm_booking_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mm_booking";
    $mm_booking_db_version = '1.0';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$mm_booking_table_name}'" ) != $mm_booking_table_name ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $mm_booking_table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            first_name varchar(255),
            last_name varchar(255),
            address varchar(255),
            lat decimal(10, 8) NOT NULL,
            lng decimal(11, 8) NOT NULL,
            field enum('option1', 'option2', 'option3'),
            phone_number varchar(255),
            email varchar(255),
            date_time_from datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            date_time_to datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      status enum('pending', 'approved', 'rejected') DEFAULT 'pending',
      modification_time datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      creation_time datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( 'mm_booking_db_version', $mm_booking_db_version );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mm_booking_activate' );
```

Comment: Thank you that kind of worked. But my problem was MaraiaDB which doesn't support multiple DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and few other things. If anyone else has this problem, I suggest running it first in phpMyAdmin and when it works just copy/paste in code. Thanks.